# Lauter Lügen - warum keine Flexion?

Tags: grammatical-case

Der Titel der 189. *Kursbuchs* heißt «Lauter Lügen». Ich hätte gedacht, «lauter» als gehobenes Adjektiv (im Sinne von reinen Lügen) wäre hier zu entweder «Lauteres Lügen» (wenn man vom Akt des Lügens spricht) oder «Lautere Lügen» (wenn man von mehreren individuellen Lügen spricht) flektiert.

Könnte jemand mir bitte die Grammatik hier erklären?

Comment: *lautere Lügen* wären ein Oxymoron.

Comment: Es ist ein anderes Wort: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/lauter_viel_viele (Anscheinend aber mit gleichem Ursprung.)

Comment: Danke, ich habe immer gedacht, dass Redewendungen wie «vor lauter Angst» waren dekliniert, aber anscheinend stimmt das nicht.

Comment: @tofro "lautere Lügen" im Sinn von "Lügen, die man reinen Gewissens ausspricht" wäre möglicherweise ein Oxymoron. Doch könnte man "lauter" ja auch im Sinne von "in seiner Zusammensetzung rein" lesen (wie *lauteres Gold*), also "reine Lügen", "Lügen ohne ein Körnchen Wahrheit", "Lügen ohne Verunreinigung durch Wahrheit".

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lauter#Adverb

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich würde das undeklinierbare *lauter* auch eher als Adverb einordnen - Es hat mMn mehr adverbiale als adjektivische Eigenenschaften. Nur sind die meisten Wörterbücher mit mir nicht einig darin.

Comment: Du vergasst in deiner Liste der möglichen Interpretationen des Titels, dass es evtl. auch um das Gegenteil von "Leiser Lügen" hätte gehen können ... 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das Wort *lauter* existiert in zwei verschiedenen, wahrscheinlich voneinander abgeleiteten Versionen:

- *lauter* im Sinne von "nichts als", "nur", "viele", "bloß": Dies ist ein undeklinierbares Adjektiv. Wörterbücher sind sich bisweilen uneinig, ob das ein nur umgangssprachlich verwendetes Wort ist - Um dieses Wort handelt es sich in deinem Beispiel

  > Helgoland - wohin ich auch schaue, lauter Wasser!
  >
  > Schöne Party, lauter nette Menschen hier!
- *lauter* als deklinierbares, "normales" Adjektiv mit der Bedeutung "rein", "unverfälscht" und in übertragener Bedeutung "ehrlich". Das passt natürlich nicht sehr gut als Eigenschaft zu Lügen. Dieses Wort wird nicht mehr sehr häufig verwendet und gilt schon fast als archaisch.

  > Er ist ein lauterer Mann
  >
  > Der Ring ist von lauterem Gold

Natürlich gibt es noch eine dritte Bedeutung, den Komparativ von *laut*, aber das war hier nicht gefragt.

Comment: _Trump lügt lauter_

Comment: *Trump verkündet alternative Wahrheiten lauter*